# how to add field slug of post on comment table references on post table when insert new comment automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with reference slug on my table comment.
i want to add **slug post** from table posts.

so when i insert comment, it can put commentable_slug from post table. Here are my comment table and post table. commentable_id = 32, it's mean post_id and you can see slug from post, that is (quia-pariatur-expedita-vel-quia)

comment table
[image]

post table
[image]

and my migration

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('commentable_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('commentable_slug')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('commentable_slug')->references('slug')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

i use null in commentable_slug because it's always warn me **Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails**.

when i was tried that my field commentable **is null**.

my comment model and relation

```
 class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
    }
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

and my post model

```
    class Post extends Model
    {
     public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function comments()
        {
            return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->whereNull('parent_id');
        }
    }
```

where part of code  is wrong?
the expected result must be:
[image]

how to solve my problem ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you would like to reference `slug` since you have `id` referencing the post already. Any specific reason for such a decision?

Comment: Because i want to link every comment to show where comments. If i use post id or (commentable id) then i get 404 error because i use bind post with slug.  So i need slug to get that. There are not relation that shows relationshop between comment and post slug, just id.

Comment: What are other ways to do that? I just need slug of post

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve, its really not that clear.  As Charlie has said you shouldn't need to link a slug if you are already linking the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand what you are trying to do.  The problem is here

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Because its a polymorphic relationship you cant use a standard `belongsTo` as you don't have a `post_id` in your table.

You need to use a `morphTo` function like this in your comment model

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

So when you call

```
$comment->commentable()->get();
```

It will then return whatever polymorphic model is linked.

Bit hard to give a precise code example as you haven't really given any use case.

But as said in the comments you should not need to link both id and slug.  Also I believe MySQL has issues when using text fields for keys and I think you need to specify a field length, but not 100% on that, maybe someone who knows more about MySQL could confirm that.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. actually, the problem is how to call slug using morph relation. sorry, if my question doesn't clear.

finally, i can get the slug without create field(commentable_slug) again or create post_id.

i get the slug of post using
`$comment->commentable->slug` .